# Timeline effect CSS only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, background

Here is a demo with the result I want to acheve:

https://ultimateelementor.com/widgets/timeline/#content_timeline

There is centered gray (inactive) line, which goes purple (active) when scrolling. Can someone give ideas how this can be made with **CSS only**.

I have tried some `background-attachment: fixed` tricks, but with no result at all.

PS: I need **only line-coloring** effect and not icons one.

**If there is no way to be done with CSS-only, I am accepting and solutions with minimum js/jquery.*

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I don't think there's any css for "during scrolling" (when scrolling) - ie to be applied at the time scrolling is in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about using position sticky.
Notes:

- Browser Support is not perfect: https://caniuse.com/css-sticky
- The body must go on after the area, so you can scroll on to fill the timeline.

```html
<div class="area"><!--General Area with the Timeline-->
  <div class="timeline-box"><!--Box with all timeline elements. Can be moved and resized-->
    <div class="baseline"></div>
    <div class="timeline">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  body {
    height: 200vh;
  }
  
  .area {
    height: 120vh;
    background: #f6f8ff;
  }
  
  .timeline-box {
    height: 120vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: clip;
    padding-left: 256px;
  }
  
  .baseline {
    width: 32px;/*Line Width*/
    height: 120vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: #d9d9e8;/* Baseline Color*/
  }
  
  .timeline {
    width: 32px;/*line width*/
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .timeline>div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120vh;
    background: #5c53f3;/*Color of the filled timeline*/
    top: -100vh;/*Starting point*/
  }
</style>
```